# When will Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 (Ultimate) Expire (Cease working)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How long will be working Visual Studio 2010 beta2 ultimate

Answer (score 7):

Beta 2 Expires on: **June 30th 2010**.  The Release Candidate expires at the same time (since they didn't initially plan on a RC release).